# Paths with DFA?

Tags: computer-science

My teacher made an example to explain DFA, it was about paths (URL paths), the rules were as follows:

```
S ::= /
S ::= /O
O ::= [a-z]
O ::= [a-z]R
O ::= [a-z]S
R ::= [a-z]
R ::= [a-z]R
R ::= [a-z]S
```

Examples of paths could be: `/foo`, `/foo/`, `foo/bar` and so on.

However, I don't understand why you would need the `R` rules since they are equal to the `O` rules.

Can I write it without the `R`? If not, why?

Comment: By DFA, do you mean Deterministic Finite Automata or something else?

Comment: I guess it is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite-state_machine.
However, the way of actually displaying it may be unorthodox in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need them, in fact. The grammar you wrote is equivalent to the one obtained by deleting the `R` rules and substituting the second `O` rule by

```
O ::= [a-z]O
```

... No idea why your teacher wrote it that way, sorry.

Comment: @Whirlwin, this is a [right regular grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar), a formal grammar having the same expressive power as a DFA.